# Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

Вот код:

```
$dir  = 'downloads';
$files = scan_dir($dir);
foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
printf(
    '<tr><td><a download href="/downloads/%s" style="color:black">%s</a></td><td style="white-space:nowrap;">%s</td></tr>',
    urlencode( $filename),
    $filename,
    human_filesize(filesize( $dir . '/' . $filename)), urlencode( $filename)
);
}

function scan_dir($dir) {
$ignored = array('.', '..', '.svn', '.htaccess');
$files = array();    
foreach (scandir($dir) as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
    $files[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
}
arsort($files);
$files = array_keys($files);
return ($files) ? $files : false;
}
```

Появляется ошибка

> PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Похоже `$files` пусто. Вы уверены, что в папке `downloads` что-то есть? проверьте также чтобы путь к папке указан правильно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поставьте проверку на `$files`, что это массив.

```
$files = scan_dir($dir);
if (is_array($files)) {
foreach($files AS $i => $filename) {
```